# Yii2 activeForm.js валидация

Tags: javascript, yii2, валидация

В общем есть массив объектов файлов вида

```
[File, File, File]
0:File
1:File
2:File
```

Каким образом можно скормить это валидатору Yii2 на клиенте ? Поделитесь пожалуйста, если кто делал подобное.

Answer (score 1):

Валидация на клиенте делается с помощью javascript.

```
var _validFileExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "gif", "png"];

$('input[type="file"]').on('change',function (e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var extansion = files[i].name.split('.')[1];
        if (!extansion)
            alert('Validation fails');
        if(!(extansion in _validFileExtensions))
            alert('Validation fails');
    }
});
```

**Валидация на сервере  - Yii2 Uploading Multiple Files:**

Во-первых, вы должны настроить класс модели, добавив опцию MAXFILES в правиле проверки файла, чтобы ограничить максимальное количество файлов, разрешенных для загрузки. Установка MAXFILES 0 означает, что нет никаких ограничений на количество файлов, которые могут быть загружены одновременно. Максимальное количество файлов могут быть загружены одновременно также ограничено с директивой PHP max_file_uploads, который по умолчанию 20. Метод download() также должны быть обновлены, чтобы сохранить загруженные файлы один за другим.

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile[]
     */
    public $imageFiles;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
    ];
}

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {
                $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

В view, вы должны добавить multiple атрибуте чтобы иметь возможность выборки несколько файлов

```
<?php
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableClientValidation'=>true,'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>

<button>Submit</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

И, наконец, в действии контроллера, вы должны вызвать  ploadedFile::getInstances() вместо ploadedFile::getInstance() присвоить массив экземплярa UploadedFile для загрузки UploadForm::imageFiles

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\UploadForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionUpload()
    {
        $model = new UploadForm();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
            if ($model->upload()) {
                // file is uploaded successfully
                return;
            }
        }
        return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html#uploading-multiple-files

Comment: Спасибо, про это все я в курсе. Вопрос в том как это реализовать средствами самого Yii, т.е. с помощью activeForm.js А так то да, можно прикрутить что-то вроде https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

Comment: echo $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]', ['enableClientValidation' => true]);

Comment: @Странник Я отвечал на вопрос в котором не было про этой сказано.Надо формулировать вопрос правильно.И не ленится при описании.Никто не обязан догадываться что  ты имел ввиду.

Comment: Там ведь сказано - валидатору Yii2 на клиенте. И да, тыкать мне не надо, мы на ты с вами не переходили.

Comment: @Странник Странно что из этого всего увидел всего лишь 2 буквы .Таким как <<вы>> не стоит помогать.Потому Что всегда найдете чем быть недовольным.Да и парням не свойственно обижаться